# Unable to populate data in Views after switching fragments

Tags: android, view, fragment, populate

As above - I can't populate data into Views (e.g. ImageView, TextView) when I switch fragments.

onCreateView - I execute AsyncTask to send request to server. 
I use interface to know when AsyncTask end its job. 
Once its done, I'm populating data into views.
It's work perfectly, but not when I switch the fragments.

I know there isn't problem with retrieving data, the only problem is with populate it into views.

Comment: In addition, everything works when I change the orientation, even if I switched fragments.

Comment: pls post your `onResue()` and `onCreateView()` code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have your code here am giving you an working example from one my my apps that sue fragments:-

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    private View mRoot;
    ....
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        updateUI();
        return mRoot;
    }

    private void updateUI() {
       TextView1 = (TextView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.id1);
       TextView2 = (TextView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.id2);
       ....
       ....
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Now that I see your code try changing the individual views by `rootView`

```
final ConstraintLayout treeline_Tier = (ConstraintLayout) treelineView.findViewById(R.id.treeline);
```

`treelineView` **-->** `rootView`

Comment: Actually these Views aren't the ones which I worry about BUT it works BUT I have three same items with different IDs which all children of these items have the same ID and in some cases data isn't populating in right place (View).

Comment: Wow, you pointed me the solution of problem.
I guess I cannot explain how you and how I did it.
Thread can be closed, problem is solved.

Comment: Cool! Glad this helped you - do you mind up voting the ans so that it helps ppl searching and reaching here later for similar issues